# Automatically downloading data from online database

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

This might not be possible, but I am trying to create an MS Access database that uses information from the table in this link:

http://si3.bcentral.cl/Indicadoressiete/secure/Serie.aspx?gcode=PRE_TCO&param=RABmAFYAWQB3AGYAaQBuAFMALQAkADYAbgBNAGgAaAAkADUAVwBQAC4AbQBYADAARwBOAGUAYwBjACMAQQBaAHAARgBhAGcAUABTAGUAdwA1ADQAMQA0AE0AawBLAF8AdQBDACQASABzAG0AXwA2AHQAawBvAFcAZwBKAEwAegBzAF8AbgBMAHIAYgBDAC4ARQA3AFUAVwB4AFIAWQBhAEEAOABkAHkAZwAxAEEARAA=

EDIT: one user thinks the link is suspicious. If you do not trust it, search Google for "Chile Central Bank Statistics Database". Then, navigate to the "observed dollar" series. I included the link to make it easier for people.

Does anyone know whether this is possible? I am very new to this - ideally, I would like to do it in VBA.

Thank you!

Comment: @MattHall why not? It's the Chilean central bank website...

Comment: @ar1994 well look at it... who would have any idea what that really links to?!

Comment: @MattHall I'm sorry - I'm not that familiar with the customs on this site. you can see, though, at the very beginning of the link that the link takes you to a central bank website. How does that make it suspicious?...

Comment: @ar1994 sorry for being suspicious, but it isn't totally clear (with all the &param gobbledygook) what you're likely to get at the end of it. Anyway, there's an Excel export option, which you could download and then import in to Access.

Comment: @MattHall No worries; usually it's better in life to question things. I noticed the excel export button, however, I would like to be able to download the data into my database daily without needing to physically open the website in my browser. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method is to download the page as is to "Daily Indicators.htm".

Go to External Data, More, HTML Document.

Select Folder, select the file, mark Create a link ..., click OK.

Mark: Show HTML tables, select Daily Indicators3, click Advanced, set Dot as decimalseparator. Click OK, Next.

Check First row contains columnheads. Click Next.

Adjust each column to Currency, finish and save.

Now, all you need to update the table is to download the page:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) _
    As Long

Public Function DownloadFile( _
    ByVal strURL As String, _
    ByVal strLocalFilename As String) _
    As Long

' Download file or page with public access from the web.
' 2004-12-17. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

' Usage, download a file:
' lngRet = DownloadFile("http://www.databaseadvisors.com/Graphics/conf2002/2002ConferencePicsbySmolin/images/dba02smolin27.jpg", "c:\happybassett.jpg")
'
' Usage, download a page:
' lngRet = DownloadFile("http://www.databaseadvisors.com/conf2002/conf200202.asp", "c:\dbaconference.htm")

' Returns 0 if success, error code if not.
' Error codes:
' -2146697210 "file not found".
' -2146697211 "domain not found".

' Limitation.
' Does not check if local file was created successfully.

    Dim lngRetVal As Long

    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL & vbNullChar, strLocalFilename & vbNullChar, 0, 0)

    DownloadFile = lngRetVal

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: **Yes**.

Typically, if a website is going to open up it's resources to you, there will either be downloadable content (CSV, TSV, etc) or an API/Web service call that you can make that will probably return JSON in this scenario.

At the top right of the page you linked, you can export this information to Excel. From Excel, you can import directly into a table in Access using VBA.

I'm assuming you wanted your information to be real-time, or something? You could probably build a web app that can automate this process, but it's not cookie-cutter.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I thought perhaps I could query the page. I'm not very familiar with any of this, but after right clicking in Chrome and clicking "Inspect Element", I could see the numbers I wanted in the html. I thought that maybe I could download some of these (perhaps this is delusional)

Comment: So, you can use JavaScript for that piece, but from there, how are you going to get it to Access? You can connect to your database via JavaScript, but the data won't be in an acceptable format. If VBA was more like a true server-side code, this would be easy, but without a server-side language you're going to go through a lot of difficulty in my opinion.

Comment: I've never used Javascript before but that sounds like an interesting approach. What if I only need one number each time? Does this make it feasible?

Comment: It looks like it would be difficult, since most browsers kind of "did away" with `ActiveX`, and thats what Microsoft used in its' browsers to connect to Access.